# Alternating Bertrand series

Tags: summation, logarithms, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

It is known that 
$$\frac{\partial^n\zeta(s)}{\partial s^n}=(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{\log^nk}{k^s}}$$

Can the following alternating version of the sum be expressed in terms of well-known functions such as the Riemann zeta?

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\log^nk}{k^s}}$$

Comment: What is the Dirichlet series of $(1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$ and its derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Recall the definition of the polylogarithm function
$$\mathrm{Li}_s(z)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{z^k}{k^s}$$
So
$$-\mathrm{Li}_{s}(-1)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^s}$$
Can you take it from here?

One may also note the formula $$-\mathrm{Li}_s(-1)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$

Comment: Of course, thanks you.